# Get the Value of XElements that dont has Child

Tags: c#, linq

How can I get the value of a `Node` in a `XDocument` when don't has more childs ?

```
<Contacts>
      <Company>
          <Name>Testing</Name>
          <ID>123</ID>
      </Company>
</Contacts>
```

In this case, I wanna get the value of the `<Name>` and `<ID>` element, because don't has child elements in them.

I'm trying the follow

```
protected void LeXMLNode(HttpPostedFile file)
{
    XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(file.FileName);            
    XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(rdr);            

    foreach (var name in doc2.Root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>().Select(x => x.Name).Distinct())
    {
        XElement Contact = (from xml2 in doc2.Descendants(name.ToString())                                    
                            where xml2.Descendants(name.ToString()).Count() == 0
                            select xml2).FirstOrDefault();

        string nome = name.ToString();
    }           
}
```

but without success, because my foreach pass in all `Elements` and I wanna get just the value of `Elements` that don't has childs.

Comment: Once you have the Name and ID elements you should use the Value property of XElement to retrieve the element text http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.Root.Elements("Company").Elements()
                .Where(item => !item.HasElements).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

See `XElement.HasElements`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.haselements.aspx